# Blackberry OS app with Phonegap

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am trying to develop mobile apps using phonegap and one of the platforms I plan to target is BBOS. However when I do installed phone gap using npm **install -g phonegap** it downloads the latest version of phonegap which does not support Blackberry OS other than Blackberry10.

So I decided to download Phonegap 2.9.1 directly which comes with all of Blackberry OS platform. My question now is that how do I use this to create and build my app?

Comment: Have you checked the [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/index.html)? Specifically the [BlackBerry Platform Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#BlackBerry%20Platform%20Guide)?

Comment: yes i did that already. i think it focuses only on the latest version which doesn't  support bbos

Comment: BB7 + legacy phonegap = fun. Good luck with that. Anyway the way this was done in previous versions of PG is to copy the sample project and tweak it. Here you have a [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0rc1/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry) to the old getting started.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually visited this page before. I think I will better appreciate if you can mail give me a direct link to download an olders version of phonegap. Thanks

Comment: is anyone found the link for that cordova sample project?